# Nesting templates in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have this view model

```
var ViewModel = function (groups) {
    var self = this;

    self.groups = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(groups, function (group) {
        return {
            planName: ko.observable(group.Key),
            documents: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(group.Values, function(value) {
                return {
                    displayCrudLinks: ko.observable(value.displayCrudLinks),
                    document: ko.observable(value.Document)
                };
            }))
        };
    }));
};
```

And I'm trying to use a template in this way (the inner span of the second template is just to check that it's working for each document, eventually I need to bind to properties of the document itself). I'm getting the "planName", but nothing under it, doesn't seem to work the foreach for documents

```
<script type="text/html" id="documentsTmpl">
    <div class="PlanDocuments">
        <div data-bind="text: planName" class="PlanName">
            <div data-bind="template: { name: 'docFragmentTmpl', foreach: documents }" class="Preview"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="docFragmentTmpl">
    <span>Document</span>
</script>
```

I couldn't even make it work just using a single template

```
<script type="text/html" id="documentsTmpl">
    <div class="PlanDocuments">
        <div data-bind="text: planName" class="PlanName">
            <div data-bind="foreach: documents" class="Preview">Document</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The groups I'm passing to the mapping function have the following structure@

```
[{Key: "General", Values: [{DisplayCrudLinks: true, Document: {...bunch of simple properties}}, ...]}, ....]
```

Thanks for any help

EDIT

I have forgotten the html for the binding

```
<div id="list" data-bind="template: { name: 'documentsTmpl', foreach: groups }"></div>
```

Comment: documents is an **observableArray** so you need to access it using **()** try this and tell me

Comment: Thanks @ebramtharwat but I tried this and didn't work

Comment: The `text` binding on the container `div` may be removing the content.  What were you hoping to achieve with that?  Could you try removing the `text` binding?

Comment: They are documents grouped by the plan they are attached to, and this text binding shows the plan name on top of the list of documents attached to it

Comment: Ouch, you are right @SteveGreatrex. I was closing the div for the plan name after the foreach one.